# question about meaning of `off-service`

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, north-american-english

There is a sentence in an article which says : "Workers are hard-pressed to finish work during a *tight off-service* window". Can anyone explain my questions :

```
1. does *tight off-service* mean *tight schedule* 
2. why there is a - between *hard-pressed* and *off-service*.
```

Any comments are welcomed. Thanks

Comment: Without full context, I'm guessing a bit. But most likely a "tight off-service schedule" means that the work schedule allows very little time for the "worker handover process". If the workers were *bus drivers*, for example, there would be a few minutes allowed within the ***bus*** schedule for the driver changeover process, during which time the "service" (carrying of passengers to their destination) would be "suspended". But whatever their job, these people are "hard-pressed" (they find it difficult) to keep to the schedule, because there's not enough time allowed for worker changeovers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An "off-service window" sounds similar to a "maintenance window" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_window That is, a scheduled time when the machine or system is not available for service. "Window" is used in sense 5. in https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/window i.e. a period of time.

English is pretty flexible when it comes to spelling compound nouns and adjectives: sometimes they are spelled as two words; sometimes they are hyphenated; and sometimes they are run together. There will often be variants in use at the same time. For example, https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/hard-pressed also gives "hard pressed" as a variant form.